# Error in function arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, function, n-gram

I have created a function that will clean the text then do unigram, bigram, and trigram but I get this error:

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
>   check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows:
>   30, 19, 10

the function works with some columns and the other not work with and I got this error and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
why <- function(L) {

  L <- removePunctuation(L)
  L <- gsub("^[[:space:]]*","",L)
  unigram <- L %>% 
       tokens() %>% 
       tokens_ngrams(n = 1, concatenator = " ") %>% 
       dfm() %>% 
       topfeatures(30)
  df1 <- data.frame(word_unigram = names(unigram), count_unigram = unigram)
  rownames(df1) <- NULL 
  bigram <- L %>% 
       tokens() %>%     
       tokens_ngrams(n = 2, concatenator = " ") %>% 
       dfm() %>% 
       topfeatures(30)
  df2 <- data.frame(word_bigram = names(bigram), count_bigram = bigram)
  rownames(df2) <- NULL

  trigram <-L %>% 
       tokens() %>% 
       tokens_ngrams(n = 3, concatenator = " ") %>% 
       dfm() %>% 
       topfeatures(30)
  df3 <- data.frame(word_trigram = names(trigram), count_trigram = trigram)
  rownames(df3) <- NULL 

  return(list(df1, df2, df3))
}

datafinal <- data.frame(lapply(data[16:21], function (L) why(L)))
```

Even if I pass one column from `data[16:21]` it does not work. Any help?

here is some sample data:

```
  N             O       P                  Q            R                 S  
 yes            no     no                  no          happy birthday   
I am happy             hello friends       I am student                   yes
```

Comment: hi, can you post the output of `dput(data[16:21])`?

Comment: I can't, but it is a 'data.frame': 115 obs. of  6 variables: and all are chr

Comment: Then just the top rows or anything we can work with. Difficult to help if we cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: I added sample data on the question, the letters are the columns name

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with the data you have provided.
Also please include all the relevant packages.

Comment: I think that because of the result of the return function (df1, df2, df3), the function most return 30 topfeatures so that mean 30 rows, and some columns had a lot of empty rows so when it returns can't Ribind the data (df1, df2, df3) because they are not in the same length.but I don't know how to write in the function if the ngram can't generate 30 rows put NA .